# servlet filter for url rewriting makes gwt page getting 404

Tags: gwt, url-rewriting, servlet-filters

I have a GWT application  `/application.html`

for easy access (and SEO) I would like make url rewriting like `/station/fr/foo` mapping

I'm trying with a *servlet filter* declared like this

> `url-pattern : /station/*`

and in this filter, I split parts of the url to build parameters for the target url:

and I do :

> `request.getRequestDispatcher( targetUrl ).forward( request, response);`

But it seems to try accessing `/station/Application.html` and then 404

[ =========== edited from here =========== ]

Well, know, since this question, I understood a few things:  the html page is reached, but tries to load his resources (css, js, img) in `/station/`

This behaviour is done by the browser (!)

If I had `<base href="http://servername/">` it works, but I can't get dev mode working anymore...

Is there's a way to transparently  modify on the fly the response to change paths in html source ?

Answer (score 0):

You are looking for fixing the app path in both hosted jetty mode and tomcat/deployment mode to be same - Try https://groups.google.com/d/topic/google-web-toolkit/a8OsRmMSaMg/discussion

```
<?xml version="1.0"  encoding="UTF-8"?> 
<!DOCTYPE Configure PUBLIC "-//Mort Bay Consulting//DTD Configure//EN" 
"http://jetty.mortbay.org/configure.dtd"> 
<Configure class="org.mortbay.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext"> 

        <Set name="contextPath">/yourapp</Set> 

</Configure>
```